# When to call gettoken, refresh token and verify token by user in jwt in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, token

I have been using built in **token authentication** for my projects in Django rest framework. But now I am shifting to **simple jwt**. But I am confused on one thing.

In Token Authentication user if logged in from front end returns a token, but in jwt documentation I have seen three requests as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [    
url(r'^auth-jwt/', obtain_jwt_token),     
url(r'^auth-jwt-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),     
url(r'^auth-jwt-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
 ]
```

I dont quite understand these requests. As a normal user, when a user visits a site he doesn't ask to get token, refresh token and verify token, he simply logs in and uses the features of the site. So, I am asking when these requests are made?

I hope I have explained well.

Answer (score 1):

The usual flow of JWT authentication goes likes this:

1. The client will send a `POST` request with the authentication credentials, which need to be verified. If the credentials are valid the server needs to return JWT Token and a refresh token. This process is handled by the `url(r'^auth-jwt/', obtain_jwt_token)` URL.
2. The token returned after authentication is a short-lived token and to continue the user session, the client needs to get a new token using the refresh token.
   This is done by `url(r'^auth-jwt-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token)` URL.

The third URL is not always required. You can use it to validate your JWT token in case it's required by your application.

Comment: In Token authentication, I have this user login api which is 127.0.0.0:8000/api/login, from where the user can log in, user never have to call url(r'^auth-jwt/', obtain_jwt_token), so I am quite confused. Is this and refresh token is automatically called from the frontend??

Comment: You should spend some time understanding how JWT authentication works and that will help to clear your doubts. Here is a good article https://www.remoteinning.com/blog/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework